# ConvertTo-HTML not working the way I thought it might in Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I have recently started my journey with Powershell. My IT manager thought it would be a good idea to give me projects to complete. I am understanding Powershell more and more but I have run into quite the road block and need some assistance. The ConvertTo-HTML at the end of my code works, as in I get the file I need in the specified directory. However, I cannot get data to show in the HTM file. Any suggestions? Again, this is my very first script I have attempted on my own.

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like '[enternamehere]*'} | Select -Expand DNSHostName

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    Invoke-Command -Computer $computer -scriptblock {
        (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name).Name
        Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName *[entertasknamehere]* | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
    }
}

ConvertTo-Html | Out-file -FilePath "[enterfilepathhere]"
```

Comment: You don't supply any input to `ConvertTo-Html`, how is it supposed to know what to put into the html document? :-)

Comment: That's a good question. Being a noob sucks :(.